# Cant get pane centered in Borderpane

Tags: javafx, borderpane

Ok so I am in a basic programming class, and we have to make a borderpane that has all the different panes inside of it.  When i try to put just a regular pane in the center with a "hello" button inside it the button gets put on the top the borderpane.  All of the other panes I use a method that makes 5 buttons and randomly inserts a word and randomly rotates it.  How do i get the pane to be in the center and not the top

```
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Button[] buttons = new Button[5];
    buttons = createButtons();
    root.getChildren().addAll(buttons);

    FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
    Button[] buttons1 = new Button[5];
    buttons1 = createButtons();
    flow.getChildren().addAll(buttons1);

    HBox hbox= new HBox();
    Button[] buttons2 = new Button[5];
    buttons2 = createButtons();
    hbox.getChildren().addAll(buttons2); 

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    Button[] buttons3 = new Button[5];
    buttons3 = createButtons();
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(buttons3);

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Hello");
    pane.getChildren().add(btn);

    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    border.setBottom(hbox);
    border.setLeft(root);
    border.setRight(vbox);
    border.setTop(flow);
    border.setCenter(pane);
    Scene scene = new Scene(border, 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Buttons");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a background color for identification, e. g. via setStyle("-fx-background-color:black). This way you see how each of your panes are laid out.

Example:

```
public class BindIt extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
        Button[] buttons = new Button[5];
        buttons = createButtons();
        root.getChildren().addAll(buttons);

        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
        flow.setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue");
        Button[] buttons1 = new Button[5];
        buttons1 = createButtons();
        flow.getChildren().addAll(buttons1);

        HBox hbox= new HBox();
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");
        Button[] buttons2 = new Button[5];
        buttons2 = createButtons();
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(buttons2); 

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color:yellow");
        Button[] buttons3 = new Button[5];
        buttons3 = createButtons();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(buttons3);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:cyan");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Hello");
        pane.getChildren().add(btn);

        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        border.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black");
        border.setBottom(hbox);
        border.setLeft(root);
        border.setRight(vbox);
        border.setTop(flow);
        border.setCenter(pane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(border, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Buttons");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private Button[] createButtons() {
        return new Button[] { new Button( "Button") };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

It gives you this:

[image]

Now you see that the center pane is in the center and fills the center. The problem is that the button isn't in the center. The easy solution is to just use a StackPane for the center pane:

```
StackPane pane = new StackPane();
```

Another solution would be to relocate the button to the center of the center pane. But then you'd have to consider resizing of the parent.